# Cannot remove a firewall service previously created

Tags: centos, firewall, services

I've added a new service in my CentOS server using the following command:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=wiremock
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

then I've removed it through

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --remove-service=wiremock
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

when I do `firewall-cmd --get-services`, I can still the service enumerated in the returned list. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [man page](https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewall-cmd.html) is a bit vague about these options, but the `--add-service` and `--remove-service` options are actually used to enable or disable a specific firewalld service. See the [Fedora Wiki page](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Firewalld?rd=FirewallD#Permanent_zone_handling) for clearer examples.

On the other hand, the `--get-services` option returns a list of firewalld services predefined on that particular system. Enabling/disabling a service has no effect on this list, because it is based on the discovery of XML files that define these services.

In your case, you should find a service definition file named `wiremock.xml` (or similar) under the `/usr/lib/firewalld` directory or `/etc/firewalld`. Removing this specific XML file will unlist the service. If you have not added this service definition yourself, you should first check where it came from. If it was shipped as part of a package, reinstalling/updating that package will restore the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you created a new service with `firewall-cmd --permanent --new-service=my-service`, the service definition xml file will be in `/etc/firewalld/services/`. Deleting that file will remove it from the list in `--get-services`, etc. The ones in `/usr/lib/firewalld/services/` normally should be only ones installed by the firewalld system packages.

I haven't seen a way to remove such a created service with firewall-cmd.